# determine if a file on the server exists

Tags: asp.net

I'm reading a file that may or may not be on the server like this:

```
string TheFile = System.IO.File.
ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\Scripts\\MyScript.js"));
```

If the file is not there, it throws an exception. I could control this with a try/catch but I was wondering if there's a way to know if a file exists using a less dramatic approach.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way by giving relative path in MapPath with forward slash. More about MapPath as under.

- Server.MapPath(".") returns the current physical directory of the file (e.g. aspx) being executed
- Server.MapPath("..") returns the parent directory
- Server.MapPath("~") returns the physical path to the root of the
  application
- Server.MapPath("/") returns the physical path to the root
  of the domain name

  ```
  if(File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/MyScript.js"))
  { 

  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use, wait for it, `File.Exists(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use FileInfo object.